# Select duplicate tag id in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

How do I get the duplicate tag id using Xpath. For eg:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male
            <sexuality>Heterosexual</sexuality>
        </gender>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <age>35</age>
        <name>Lisa
            <lastname>Monyet</lastname>
        </name>
        <gender>Female</gender>
        <role>CEO</role>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>40</age>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Manager</role>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Another question is,

Does this XPath query : `//Employee/*` able to return the tag id alongside the rest of the nodes value. If not, how do I improve this?

Comment: This is illegal xml. id attributes are supposed to be unique in a document.

Comment: I would think about preprocessing to change the id to something else e.g. id2, then use something like `count(//Employee/@id2)>1` in my XPath expression. ... not tested!!

Comment: @BillNaylor *"This is illegal xml. id attributes are supposed to be unique"* That's not true. That kind of restrictions are imposed by specific XML vocabularies like XHTML. **This is a "valid" XML document**

Comment: Here you have two question. I think you should choose for wich one you want an answer. Also, are you asking how to get the `id` attribute having an already present value?

Comment: I have done some reading up on this at [https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/], it is attributes of type ID which must be unique, as per the DTD. Certainly if you prepend the given document with `<!DOCTYPE Employees [<!ATTLIST Employee id ID #IMPLIED>]>` It becomes invalid. To me at least it seems confusing to have non-unique `id` attributes, or is this your use-case @user6185827 (to detect such occurrences)?

Answer (score 1):

Including `id` in the query just works

```
xmllint -xpath '//Employee[@id="1"]' test.xml
```

Result:

```
    <Employee id="1">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Pankaj</name>
        <gender>Male
            <sexuality>Heterosexual</sexuality>
        </gender>
        <role>Java Developer</role>
    </Employee><Employee id="1">
        <age>40</age>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <gender>Male</gender>
        <role>Manager</role>
    </Employee>
```